# JSON parsing with mantle

Tags: ios, json

I want to parse this JSON: https://api.guildwars2.com/v1/world_names.json?lang=en
I use Mantle. So I made two classes: server and serverList.

//server.m:

```
@implementation GW2Server

+ (NSDictionary *)JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey
{
    return @{
             @"serverID": @"id",
             @"serverName": @"name",
             };
}

+ (NSValueTransformer *)serverIDJSONTransformer
{
    return [MTLValueTransformer reversibleTransformerWithBlock:^(NSString *stringFromJSON){
        NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
        [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
        return [formatter numberFromString:stringFromJSON];
    }];
}

+ (NSValueTransformer *)serverNameJSONTransformer
{
    return [MTLValueTransformer reversibleTransformerWithBlock:^(NSString *stringFromJSON){
        return stringFromJSON;
    }];
}

@end
```

//serverList.m

```
@implementation GW2ServerList

+(NSDictionary *)JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey
{
    return @{
             @"serverID": @"serverList.serverID",
             @"serverName": @"serverList.serverName",
             };
}

+ (NSValueTransformer *)serverListJSONTransformer
{
    return [MTLValueTransformer mtl_JSONArrayTransformerWithModelClass:[GW2Server class]];
}

@end
```

The problem is when I try to use  [MTLJSONAdapter modelOfClass:[GW2ServerList class] fromJSONDictionary:jSONDict error:NULL], looks like it can't work with JSON arrays. And my JSON actually is array. So how can I resolve this issue? 
I could get JSON array and then parse every object in it with Mantle, but looks like there is a better way which I don't know.

UPD: it's obvious that the problem is in serverList which consist of a single array of "server" objects. But I don't know how to rewrite JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey correctly for it (because there is no such object as array in JSON - it's array by itself or something like that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved!
All I should do is to make dictionary from JSON array like this:

```
NSArray *jSONArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0
                                                                   error:NULL];
NSDictionary *jSONDict = @{@"serverList": jSONArray};
```

And then it will be possible to parse it as usual:

```
self.serverList = [MTLJSONAdapter modelOfClass:[GW2ServerList class]
                                        fromJSONDictionary:jSONDict
                                                     error:NULL];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just an a complete example of @Maria solution also using Mantel

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"person" ofType:@"json"];
NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];
NSLog(@"%@", dataDictionary);
EventParticipant* ev = [MTLJSONAdapter modelOfClass:[EventParticipant class]
                            fromJSONDictionary:dataDictionary
                                         error:NULL];
```